# Counting sort and usage in Java applications

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I did an algoritms refresher and I (re)read about a sorting algorithm that runs in linear time, namely `Counting Sort`.

To be honest I had forgotten about it.
I understand the structure and logic and the fact that it runs in linear time is a very attactive quality.

But I have the folowing question:
As I understanding the concrete implementation of the algorithm relies on 2 things:
1) The range of input numbers is small (otherwise the intermediate array will be huge and with many gaps).
2) We actually know the range of numbers.

Taking that these 2 assumptions are correct (please correct me otherwise), I was wondering what is the best application domain that this algorithm applies to.
I mean specifically in Java, is an implementation like the following [Java/Counting sort](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Counting_sort) sufficient:

```
public static void countingSort(int[] a, int low, int high)
{
    int[] counts = new int[high - low + 1]; // this will hold all possible values, from low to high
    for (int x : a)
        counts[x - low]++; // - low so the lowest possible value is always 0

    int current = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
    {
        Arrays.fill(a, current, current + counts[i], i + low); // fills counts[i] elements of value i + low in current
        current += counts[i]; // leap forward by counts[i] steps
    }
}
```

or it is not a trivial matter to come up with the `high` and `low`?

Is there a specific application in Java that counting sort is best suited for?

I assume there are subtleties like these otherwise why would anyone bother with all the `O(nlogn)` algorithms?

Answer (score 3):

`Algorithms` are not about the language, so this is language-agnostic. As you have said - use counting sort when the domain is small. If you have only three numbers - `1, 2, 3` it is far better to sort them with `counting sort`, than a `quicksort`, `heapsort` or whatever which are `O(nlogn)`. If you have a specific question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes, you are right.But still there are certain properties of specific algorithms that makes them more appropriate in some context than another.An answer I would be looking for is e.g. We use counting sort extensively in Android apps because it is fast and for the following reasons etc.

Comment: @user384706 - Counting sort won't get faster because the platform is `Android`. If it is the appropriate algorithm in the situation, it should be used, no matter if it is Android, Java, PHP, C#, Ruby on Rails or whatever.

Comment: Petar:Yes of course it will not be faster for `Android`.But for application that has specific requirements related to performance e.g. mobile applications etc, Counting Sort I assume would be very attractive.But is it actually prefered or does these assumes that it relies on, actually make it not easy to be used so frequently?

Comment: Maybe you are confused about algorithm complexity. Algorithm complexity is the same no matter what the platform or language is. Counting sort is really bad when the numbers are big. So if you know that the numbers can be big, don't use it. It relies on the simple fact that the numbers are small. When you know that the numbers will be small - use it.

Comment: @PetarMinchev By the way, when you say "... If you have only three numbers - 1, 2, 3 ..." that means "3 _types_ of numbers" right? E.g., {2,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,1,1,2,3,1,3,2,3,2,1} is a good candidate for counting sort right?

Comment: Yes, I mean "3 types".

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect to say counting sort is `O(n)` in the general case, the "small range of element" is not a recommendation but a key assumption.

> Counting sort assumes that each of the elements is an integer in the
>   range 1 to k, for some integer k. **When k = O(n)**, the Counting-sort
>   runs in O(n) time.

In the general situation, the range of key `k` is independent to the number of element `n` and can be arbitrarily large. For example, the following array:

> {1, 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}

As for the exact break even point value of `k` and `n` where counting sort outperform traditional sort, it is hugely dependent on the implementation and best done via **benchmarking (trying both out)**.